# PyQGIS Processing script crashes QGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to write a Python script in QGIS 2.18.16 to use zonal statistics of a multi-band raster (GeoTIFF) using a polygon shapefile.

QGIS crashes turning off so I can't get any error message to correct my code.

I'm working in Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in QGIS?

```
import processing 
vectorlayer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layer(0)
rasterfile = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().layer(1).source()

processing.runalg("qgis:zonalstatistics", rasterfile, 3, vectorlayer, "Zonal_", True, "/media/giacomo/4A48-5E67/prova/out.shp")
```

Comment: Did you type `print vectorlayer` and `print rasterfile` to ensure you're using the correct order of layers?

Comment: Hi. Yes, it is a multiple bands raster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way.

```
from qgis.analysis import QgsZonalStatistics

pathFileRaster = "G:\\prova\\VHVV.tif"
pathFileVector = "G:\\prova\\ROI_polygons_Rothamsted_2014-2015\\ROI_polygons_Rothamsted_2014-2015.shp"

pathFileRasterQgs = QgsRasterLayer(pathFileRaster, "stack")
pathFileVectorQgs = QgsVectorLayer(pathFileVector, "ROI", 'ogr')

nBands = pathFileRasterQgs.bandCount()
listBands = range(1, (nBands+1))

for iBand in listBands:

    calc = QgsZonalStatistics(pathFileVectorQgs, \
    pathFileRaster , \
    'b_', \
    int(iBand), \
    QgsZonalStatistics.Mean #because I need only the mean)

    calc.calculateStatistics(None)
```